# Extremely high loading times - Requests not running async. Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

**Overview**

I've built an application with Vue, Express and MongoDB (mongoose ORM).
On loading the landing page, a series of GET requests are made for various bits of data. The loading times are extremely high, I've recorded some times as high as 22s for a particular route. It's lead me to believe that my requests are running sequentially, despite specifying in my logic that everything should run async

I've tried reducing the size of the objects being returned from the requests as well as using the `.lean()` method. These attempts shaved off a couple of seconds, but the overall issue is not remotely sorted. Times are still stupid high. To give an example:

From This:

```
// Method to find all users
var users = await User.find({});
```

To:

```
// Method to find all users
var users = await User.find({}, "username, uid").lean();
```

On the page in question, there are about 5 main components. Each component is making a get request. One of these is a Chat Column and the code for it is as follows:

ChatCol.vue

```
beforeMount () {
    this.$store.dispatch('retrieve_chat')
}
```

Store.js (am using Vuex store)

```
retrieve_chat (context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios({
                    url: api.dev + 'api/v1/chat',
                    method: 'GET',
                })
                .then(res => {
                    context.commit('set_chat', res.data)
                    resolve(res);
                }).catch(err => {
                    // alert(err)
                    reject(err);
                })
            })
        },
```

Requests in this format are being made on all the components. About 5 of them in the page in question.

**Backend / Server Code**

To give some context into the requests being made.
The client will hit the route 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/chat'

and the code that makes the request on the server is the following:

```
var Chat = require("../models/ChatMessage");

module.exports = {
    // LIMIT CHAT TO 100 MESSAGES
    async get_chat(req, res) {
        Chat.find({}, function(err, messages) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    message: "Interval Server Error", 
                    type: "MONGO_CHAT_DOCUMENT_QUERY", 
                    err: err, 
                })
            }

            if (!messages) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: "Resource not found", 
                    type: "MONGO_CHAT_DOCUMENT_QUERY", 
                    details: "!messages - no messages found", 
                })
            }

            messages.reverse();
            return res.status(200).json({
                messages, 
            });
        }).sort({"_id": -1}).limit(30);
    },
}
```

If I look at the network tab on the chrome dev tools, this is how the requests appear. Apologies for the long winded post, I literally have no idea what is causing this

**Important Note:**

It was mentioned to me that mongodb has this feature where it locks when mutating the data, and I thought that might be the case, but there are no mutations taking place. It's just 3/4 get requests happening in parallel, albeit pretty big requests, but they shouldn't be taking as long as they are

**Screenshot of the network tab:**

[image]

*(ignore the failed req, and some of the duplicate named requests)*

StackOverflow sempais please help. It's a very big application and I don't know what the issue is exactly, so If I've missed out any details - Apologies, I'll clarify anything that needs clarity.

Comment: The response from your `/chat` is 17MB. Why would you possibly want to load 17MB of data to display in a web page? **Thats your real problem**, and nothing to do with looking at MongoDB internals or anything else like that. So not clear what you are actually storing in those 30 results, but 17MB is way to large for a web page, so you need to "trim the fat" that you are storing in there since there is no way it can be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I've now found what's causing such a huge amount of data to load. Appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large amount of base64 encoded data from a previously abandoned and poorly implemented image upload feature was being stored in each chat message as well as other places, causing large amounts of data to be loaded in and ultimately lead to huge loading times.

Thank you [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn).